# Spark: groupByKey with 'Iterator' instead of 'Iterable' on the right side

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an rdd. I want to group it by some property and save each group into a separate file (and get the list of result file names).
The most naive way:

```
val rdd : RDD[Long] = ???
val byLastDigit: RDD[(Int, Long)] = rdd.map(n => ((n % 10).toInt, n))
val saved: Array[String] = byLastDigit.groupByKey().map((numbers: (Int, Iterable[Long])) => {  
   //save numbers into a file
   ???
}).collect()
```

The downside of this approach is that it holds in memory all values for a key simultaneously. So it will work poorly on huge datasets.

Alternative approach:

```
byLastDigit.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(1000)).mapPartitions((numbers: Iterator[(Int, Long)]) => {
    //assume that all numbers in a partition have the same key
    ???
  }).collect()
```

Since the number of partitions is much higher than the number of keys each partition will most probably hold numbers for only one key.

It works for huge datasets smoothly. But this is ugly and much more error-prone.

Could it be done better?